# Install the latest git versions of holoviews, hvplot, panel, datashader and param

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz, panel-pyviz

The libraries of the Holoviz ecosystem are continuously updated.

Using pip, how do I install the latest git versions of:

- Holoviews
- Hvplot
- Panel
- Datashader
- Param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest github versions of the holoviz libraries can be installed as follows.

**Holoviews:**

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews.git

**Hvplot:**

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot.git

**Panel:**

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/panel.git

**Datashader:**

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/datashader.git

**Param:**

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/param.git

**Please note that for showing plots in jupyter lab you will need the pyviz jupyter lab extension:**

> jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz

Answer (score 2):

Sander's `pip install git` suggestion is easy and is appropriate if all you want to do is grab the latest version without ever editing it. But if you also want to make any local changes, then instead you can do:

```
conda install --no-deps datashader
git clone https://github.com/holoviz/datashader.git
cd datashader
pip install --no-deps -e .
cd ..
```

(and similarly for each of the other libraries). And if you further want to contribute any of your local changes back to the library repositories, you'll first want to fork the library into your own account (click "Fork" on the github homepage for the library), then clone your fork instead, then make a PR with your edits.